# Algorithm to compare hierarchical data

Tags: algorithms, trees

The task is to **compare** two trees and **determine** what are the changes. Both trees are represented as an adjacency list (ID, ParentID).

**Base tree:**

- A (ID: 1, ParentID: 1)

  - B1 (ID: 2, ParentID: 1)

    - C1 (ID: 6, ParentID: 2)

      - D1 (ID: 13, ParentID: 6)
    - C2 (ID: 7, ParentID: 2)

      - D2 (ID: 14, ParentID: 7)
  - B2 (ID: 3, ParentID: 1)

    - C3 (ID: 8, ParentID: 3)

      - D3 (ID: 15, ParentID: 8)

        - E1 (ID: 23, ParentID: 15)
  - B3 (ID: 4, ParentID: 1)

    - C4 (ID: 9, ParentID: 4)

      - D4 (ID: 16, ParentID: 9)

        - E2 (ID: 24, ParentID: 16)
        - E3 (ID: 25, ParentID: 16)
      - D5 (ID: 17, ParentID: 9)

        - E4 (ID: 26, ParentID: 17)
        - E5 (ID: 27, ParentID: 17)
    - C5 (ID: 10, ParentID: 4)

      - D6 (ID: 18, ParentID: 10)
  - B4 (ID: 5, ParentID: 1)

    - C6 (ID: 11, ParentID: 5)

      - D7 (ID: 19, ParentID: 11)
      - D8 (ID: 20, ParentID: 11)
    - C7 (ID: 12, ParentID: 5)

      - D9 (ID: 21, ParentID: 12)
      - D10 (ID: 22, ParentID: 12)

**New tree:**

- A (ID: 1, ParentID: 1)

  - B1 (ID: 2, ParentID: 1)

    - C1 (ID: 6, ParentID: 2)

      - D1 (ID: 13, ParentID: 6)
      - D2 (ID: 14, ParentID: 6)
    - B1-C2 (ID: 7, ParentID: 2)
  - B2 (ID: 3, ParentID: 1)

    - C3 (ID: 8, ParentID: 3)

      - D3 (ID: 15, ParentID: 8)

        - E1 (ID: 23, ParentID: 15)
  - B3 (ID: 4, ParentID: 1)
  - B4 (ID: 5, ParentID: 1)

    - C4 (ID: 9, ParentID: 5)

      - D4 (ID: 16, ParentID: 9)

        - E2 (ID: 24, ParentID: 16)
        - E3 (ID: 25, ParentID: 16)
      - D5 (ID: 17, ParentID: 9)

        - E4 (ID: 26, ParentID: 17)
        - E5 (ID: 27, ParentID: 17)
    - C6 (ID: 11, ParentID: 5)

      - D8 (ID: 20, ParentID: 11)
      - D10 (ID: 22, ParentID: 11)
    - C7 (ID: 12, ParentID: 5)

      - C7-D7 (ID: 19, ParentID: 12)

**Changes:**

- D2 (ID: 14) moved under C1 (ID: 6)
- C4 (ID: 9) moved under B4 (ID: 5)
- C2 (ID: 7) renamed to B1-C2
- D7 (ID: 19) renamed to C7-D7 and moved under C7 (ID: 12)
- D10 (ID: 22) moved under C6 (ID: 11)
- C5 (ID: 10) removed
- D9 (ID: 21) removed

---

One of the solutions can be to iterate through each node in the base tree, compare it to equivalent node in the new tree and then determine what is the change.

For example:

- D2 (ID: 14, ParentID: 7)

  - the name is the same
  - ParentID changed to 6
  - that means D2 was moved

---

1. Is there a more efficient way to perform such comparison?
2. Is there a well known algorithm to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Google "tree similarity" or "tree alignment".